# Grunt: throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I try to reinstall grunt, but check the version grunt get an error:

```
$npm uninstall grunt-cli -g
$npm cache clean -g
$npm install grunt-cli -g
...
/usr/bin/grunt -> /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.9 /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
└── findup-sync@0.1.2 (lodash@1.0.1, glob@3.1.21)
```

Error after installation:

```
$grunt --version

path.js:313
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    at Object.exports.resolve (path.js:313:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt:13:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

$ which grunt
/usr/local/bin/grunt

$ node --version
v0.10.15
```

**Please tell me what could be the problem?**

Comment: Maybe you have two versions installed? https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/726#issuecomment-19949327
Somewhere in /usr/local should be a package.json from grunt, make sure it's version number really is 1.9.

Comment: jgillich is right. I had that issue and removing the second reference allowed grunt to run perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jgillich thank you, your link was useful!

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/726#issuecomment-19949327